# Stop submit button to refresh the page

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `<form>` tag which has 2 buttons and 2 text fields. I have other controls as well in my form.

Following is the form tag:

```
<form>
  <input id="Text1" type="text" name="locationText" />
  <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="Search Location" />

  <input id="Text2" type="text" name="refText" />
  <input id="Button2" type="submit" value="Search Ref" />
</form>
```

When I search location, it works fine.The location drop down list is searched with the query that I gave. But, once I search location and then try to search Ref, the page gets refreshed and the previous location search is gone.

I would like to do both the search without refreshing the page. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

[image]

[image]

**Page refreshes on the second picture.**

---

Comment: since you've only got one form, you don't need two buttons. Just have one button and get the server-side code to read both values at once, and return the results. It's not clear if it returns two sets of results from different queries, or they are both parameters of the same search query? We'd have to see the server code. Either way you can easily do both at once.

Comment: @ADyson Hey thanks for your comment. They are two different queries for two different search options. If I do location search, then location drop down is updated, if I do ref search, then ref drop down is updated. If I use one button for both, it works very well. Is it not possible to use two buttons and prevent form from refreshing once the search is made?

Comment: I guess Ajax would be your best bet. Please post your server side code.

Comment: Create a view model and strongly bind to your model properties (how would you expect the values to be retained if you do bind to your model)

Comment: if you don't want a refresh to occur then you can use AJAX. What's your reason for wanting to avoid the refresh though? If you bind your form elements properly to your model in the way MVC recommends then the values should be preserved after a refresh anyway. From the little code you've posted I sense that you're not doing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using javascript then you don't need to use the form tag, you can use buttons onclick event.

You can do one of those to prevent refreshing page on form submit.

1- Change `type=submit` to `type=button`

2- Use this on your form: `<form onsubmit="return false;">`

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent refreshing by using preventDefault on form submission.

Example code:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
</form>
```

Hope this helps !